# Process specific .htm page as .php on Apache server

Tags: php, html, apache, .htaccess

I'm programming for an Apache server and I need for just one specific html page (say, first.htm) to be processed as PHP script. Is it possible to set up?

Comment: If I understand your question you can change just the file extension to .php,

Comment: This will break the external links to that page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a file called `.htaccess` and place it in the directory this file will be in. Add this line to ti:

```
<Files first.htm>
    AddType application/x-httpd-php .htm
</Files>
```

Comment: Yes, that will do it with all HTML page. I need it for just one specific page.

Comment: Thanks. Can I specify a path to the .html file as well to remove possible ambiguity?

Comment: Not necessary if you put the htaccess file in the same directory as the file.

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#files

Comment: Thanks for your help. Now I know where to look. Much appreciated.

Comment: If I may further the question: any way to set it so that all `.htm` can be set instead of a single file?

Comment: Just use `AddType application/x-httpd-php .htm` only. Ignore the tags.

Answer (score 4):

[`SetHandler`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#sethandler) directive can be used, too:

> Forces all matching files to be processed by a handler
>
> When placed into an .htaccess file or a  or 
>   section, this directive forces all matching files to be parsed through
>   the handler given by handler-name.

```
<Files first.htm>
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</Files>
```

Comment: +1 - This is actually the proper way to do it. AddType is for MIME types, which are a totally different concept and it was a mistake for PHP to recommend configuring it that way. The PHP docs no longer recommend using AddType and now recommend SetHandler.

Answer (score 2):

```
<Files first.htm>
    ForceType application/x-httpd-php
</Files>
```

Comment: Interesting. What is the difference between AddType as suggested above and ForceType?

Comment: AddType have a 2nd parameter, in johns case ".htm", ForceType chane type on all files in the current scope, while AddType change the type on all files in the scope that ends whit .htm