# PHP code showing in WAMP

Tags: php, wamp

I've tryed to setup xampp for 3 hours. Given up with that, having a bit more success with wamp how ever php code isnt compiling.

I have index.htm and header.php in my www folder.

index.htm code:

```
<?php include('header.php');?>

<body>
    <h1>This is a header</h1>
    <p>this is a paragraph</p>


</body>
</html>
```

header.php code

```
<?php
    echo "<!doctype html><html lang='en'><head><title>PAGETITLE</title></head>";
?>
```

The php code is showing instead of compiling. How do i fix this?

Comment: index.htm should be called index.php.

Comment: Rename index.htm to index.php

Comment: Someone should make note that this is just the *default* behaviour because it's easy enough to have Apache push `.html` extensions through the interpreter.  [» first SO question in search result](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11234010/process-specific-htm-page-as-php-on-apache-server)

Answer (score 3):

You can't use `<?php include('header.php');?>` in an HTML (.htm) file so please change that extension to .php and it will work.

Answer (score 1):

PHP DOES NOT work, in `.html` files. It works only in `.php` files, or `.php, .phtml, .php4 .php3, .php5, .phps`